# Ubuntu partition vanished after distro upgrade

Tags: partitioning

I've upgrade my Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 using the update manager. After the install finished (it took several hours) the system froze so i had to turn off the notebook with the power button (I've wait a long time before do it). After reboot and selecting Ubuntu (I have Ubuntu installed alongside Windows 7) it displays this message:

```
No init found. Try passing init=bootarg
```

I started Ubuntu from a live USB and try to pass the fsck command but the whole Ubuntu partition just isn't there. With `fdisk -l` it only displays 3 partitions:

```
/dev/sda1--->System_DRV 1.17 Gb  
/dev/sda2--->The Windows 7 partition 454 Gb  
/dev/sda3--->the Lenovo Recovery partition 9.77 Gb
```

The disk have 500 Gb so there's some space missing. I'm no expert in Ubuntu so I don't have many ideas on solving this problem.

When the computer starts it shows the 2 OS for selecting and if I try to fresh install Ubuntu it says that I have various OS installed and give me 2 options: Format all the disk and install only Ubuntu or manually manage my partitions (it also shows only those 3) but none of my files are there for access, I just can't manage to find that part or mount it.

I don't care to recover the files, I've made a backup of them before the upgrade, but I need Ubuntu installed, and also that space that it is occupying.

edit:
Here is the screenshot of gparted

[image]

Comment: Hmm, this is weird. Looks like your Windows partition took over. It is normal that you "miss" some space from the number on the box (so you'll never have 100% of your 500GB). When you run the following command:
```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda
```
is it complaining? Also, do you have more than one disk in your laptop?
How did you install Ubuntu?

Comment: Best to edit your question to include a current-window-only screenshot of `gparted` (when booted to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB), and we'll take a look.

Comment: With gparted or installator, you should see some 20 GB not used. Do yo?

Comment: @incredibleholg Here's the output. http://imgur.com/YJlAKjs
 And no, i only have one disk. I was making an upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS using the update manager.

Comment: This is a problem - what does the red exclamation mark says?

Answer (score 1):

***** This is an advice before the screenprint of gparted was shown, it is not enought to follow 1-3, you would need 1/ detect the problem 2/ to consider the text in italics *****

You dont need to find the partition for a fresh install.

There are few dangers, you could loose all your partitions, so **backup first.**

My experience is that Ubuntu takes about 15 GB, you need some `/tmp` space and `/home` space. Personally, *I would a) defragmented Windows7, booted from USB with `gparted` and tried to make some reasonable space for Ubuntu on behalf of Windows7.* Anyway, if you dont feel strong, or you dont care:

1) boot with Ubuntu 16.04 (you evidently use LTS editions)

2) Start with install, manually create 4th partition, that will contain two (at least) logic partitions - a 1) swap partition of a size of your RAM*2 (maybe it is possible to omit swap nowadays?) and ext4 for Ubuntu (`/`) that fills the last bytes of the disk.

3) Install to a new partition, grub should take care about the rest.

Comment: There was a question on taking care of dual boot....If not, I would recommend deleting win7 completely.  #3 - grub takes care about everything.  I would worry more in new systems, but here, Ubuntu already worked once.

Comment: My problem is that i don't have a device to make a backup. 
In case that I make a new partition for a fresh install, what will happen with the rest of the space that gone missing after the upgrade?

Comment: You said, you dont care about the files,  didnt you? Either you find (in the beginning of the installation) that there is a free space for your partition, this means your previous partition simply disappeared. Or you find, there is not enough space to create the new partitions, then, I dont know what happened, but you would need to resize Win7 partition. Every partition change is dangerous, you should make a backup.  I was lucky until now, but always I had a data bakup.

Comment: Oh - now I see a new picture  with gparted  ! What is a text comment to the problem with NTFS? Do you still see windows?

Comment: Sorry for that, i forgot to mount the drive so Gparted cannot read it. After mounted it appears fine.  http://imgur.com/bGOwnQO
Windows works and i can access all it's files from Ubuntu. I think i'll try to get a disk for backup the win7 files and make a new partition through the Ubuntu installation. I didn't found any other way. Still I don't understand why the grub shows Ubuntu, and how the whole partition dissappeared from one second to another. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You will not manage to make a new partition during install. There is no unallocated space. Whatever happened, you remained without any space on the disk for a new partition. I would do as I wrote - defrag., resize win parition, create new one (called extended) and than whatever linux partitions you like. Even from install should work.